# How do I send a Mongo Document back to the front end?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
//router    

app.get('/retrieve_report', function(req, res) {

    var retrieved = retrieve_report(req, res);

    res.render('retrieve_report.ejs', {
        'report' : retrieved
    });
});

//Load up the report model
var Report = require('../models/report');
console.log('Report ' + Report.schema);
//expose this function to our app using module.exports


//query

module.exports = function(req, res) {

    //console.log('param ' + res.send);

    var query = Report.findById(req.param('id'), function(err, doc) {
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }
        else {
            console.log('doc ' + JSON.stringify(doc));
            res.send(doc);
        }
    });
}

//app.js
var retrieve_report = require('./config/retrieve_report');//which is the above code
```

I want to return the document to the router so that I can put its information into my view.  I tried "res.json(doc), but that gave me the error, "throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');"  Everyone says to use a callback function, but aren't I using a callback function here?

Answer (score 0):

As your error says:

```
but that gave me the error, "throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');"
```

Means you are trying to send data the twice.

Sample code:

```
    app.get('/retrieve_report', function(req, res) {

   var query = Report.findById(req.param('id'), function(err, doc) {
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }
        else {
            console.log('doc ' + JSON.stringify(doc));
            res.send(doc);
        }
});
```

This should work..